# button onClick inside Formik Form does not yield expected values when passing values to parent component

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a child Formik component and I need to pass data to my parent component. In the child Formik component, I have two buttons: 
1. an onSubmit button that submits the form and goes to the next page and 
2. an onClick button that goes backwards to the last page

When I submit the form and go to the next page, everything works and checks out. However, when I go backwards to the last page, the data I am passing (which is an array []) gets transformed into a class of some sort when i console log it.

I narrowed down the problem to the 2nd button being an onClick, and not an onSubmit type. If I make the type of the 2nd button a "submit" type button, it works but it calls the onSubmit event in the Formik component. I also tried doing this:

```
<Button type="submit" onClick={() => this.submitAction = 'b'}>Back</Button>
<Button type="submit" onClick={() => this.submitAction = 'a'}>Next</Button>

and

onSubmit={values => {
if (this.submitAction === 'a') {this.props.nextStep('post1', values)}
if (this.submitAction === 'b') {this.props.lastStep('post1', values)}
}}
```

However, the problem with this approach is that both button events pass through the validationschema event, which is not what I want.

Here is my full code:

### Child Component:

```
class Post2 extends React.Component {
  submitAction = undefined;
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{ studyType: this.props.initValues.studyType }}
          onSubmit={values => {
            this.props.nextStep('post2', values)
          }} //here is my onSubmit event that gets called when the form submits
          render={({ values }) => (
            <Form>
            <div>
              <FieldArray
                name="studyType"
                render={arrayHelpers => (
                  <div>
                    {studyTypes.map(index => (
                      <div key={index}>
                        <label>
                          <input
                            name="studyType"
                            type="checkbox"
                            value={index}
                            checked={values.studyType.includes(index)}
                            onChange={e => {
                              if (e.target.checked) arrayHelpers.push(index);
                              else {
                                const idx = values.studyType.indexOf(index);
                                arrayHelpers.remove(idx);
                              }
                            }}
                          />
                          {index}
                        </label> 
                      </div>  
                    ))}
                  </div>
                )} 
              />
              <Button onClick={(value) => this.props.lastStep('post2', value)}>Back</Button> //here are my two buttons
              <Button type="submit">Next</Button> //here are my two buttons
            </div>
            </Form>
          )}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

### Parent functions and state code:

```
class FormikStepper extends React.Component {
  state = {
    activeStep: 1,
    post0: {
      title: '',
      description: '',  
    },
    post1: {
      category: [],   
    },
  };

  nextStep = (post, values) => { 
    this.setState({ activeStep: this.state.activeStep + 1, [post]: values })   
  }  //next step function which is called from child component
  lastStep = (post, values) => {   
    this.setState({ activeStep: this.state.activeStep - 1, [post]: values })   
  }  //last step function which is called from child component
```

Comment: Have you explicitly set `type="button"` for the back button? Otherwise it will als be treated as submit inside a form.

Comment: Yes. When i call my function to pass values to my parent, the array still gets transformed into:  Class {dispatchConfig: null, _targetInst: null, _dispatchListeners:.... and so on}. IF the button is a submit type button, the array does NOT get transformed into a weird Class and everything is correct. BUT i cannot have the button be of submit type since I don't want it to run through validationschema

Comment: Ok, now I see. In the onClick function you are using the input `value`which returns the button instance and the real javascript event data. But you want the values of the Formik. Try `onClick={() => this.props.lastStep('post2', values)}`. This will use the Formik parameter.

Comment: OH! that is what it does! I never really understood the differences and nuances of function writing. Thank you very much sir. Apologies for wasting anyone's time thinking this was a real question.